# reCaptcha not generated while using jquery .load()

Tags: jquery, recaptcha

I've the following codes.

Mark Up

```
        <nav id=main>
            <ul>
                <li><a id=home href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a id=about href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a id=contact  href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="page"></div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
    $('nav#main ul li a').click( function() {
       var page = $(this).attr("id");
       $('div#page').load("pages/"+page+".php");
    });
});
```

In the contact page, I've integrated reCaptcha in a form.

The contact page can be accessed using the URL `www.mydomain.com/?page=contact` directly also. While accessing the page by typing the URL in the address bar, the reCaptcha shows up fine. But when clicked on the `contact` link from the navigation and processing using the javascript I've provided above, the reCaptcha doesn't show up.

page.php

```
<div>
<form>
<?php
        require_once($captchaPath);
    $publickey = "key"; // you got this from the signup page
    echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
?>
<button name="send" type="button" value="Send">Send</button>
</form>
</div>
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: Have you checked the error console of Firefox or Safari? Perhaps the console shows an javascript error.

Comment: what is the response that you get in firebug

Comment: how do I check for errors in the console? I'm using Chrome developers tool.

Comment: ctrl+shift+j will open console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't gone through your code, but Recaptcha has updated their [URL](http://www.fistagon.us/2011/04/15/recaptcha-users-update-your-url/). Just wanted to suggest if that could be the problem.

You need to update the https://api-secure.recaptcha.net to https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api

Answer (score 0):

maybe I'm wrong, but I think you want to load the page 'contact.php', 'home.php and/or 'about.php'. you don't create any parameter.